# How can I find the sum of a string's indices in Python?

Tags: python

I am working on creating a program that has a function that takes in a string and prints the number of capital letters and also the sum of their indices.
like:
"hEllo, World"
2
8

I have figured out the capital letters but I am having trouble with the indices.

Here is what I have:

```
import sys

def Count(str):

str = sys.argv[1]

upper, lower, number, special = 0,0,0,0

for i in range(len(str)):
    if str[i].isupper():
        upper += 1
    elif str[i].islower():
        lower += 1
    elif str[i].isdigit():
        number +=1
    else:
        special += 1
        
        
print(upper)
print(lower)


Count(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by first making a list of the upper-case character positions then getting the length and sum of that list, like this

```py
def count_upper(inp_str):
    # Get a list of the indices of the upper-case characters,
    # enumerate returns a list of index,character pairs, then you
    # keep only the indices with an upper case character
    uppers = [i for i,s in enumerate(inp_str) if s.isupper()]

    # number of upper-case chars is the length of the list of indices
    num_uppers = len(uppers)

    # index sum is straightforward
    sum_indices = sum(uppers)

    return num_uppers, sum_indices
    
print(count_upper("hEllo, World"))
```

which returns

```py
(2, 8)
```

If you want to print it on two lines, just get the tuple values and print them individually, like this:

```py
c,s = count_upper("hEllo, World")
print(c)
print(s)
```

or if you want to format it, you can use something like this

```py
print("%d and %d" % (c,s))
print(f"{c} and {s}") # with python 3 f-strings
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can have the output on two lines like: 2

Comment: 2
8     Do you know how I can have it in this format? I thought maybe \n but that didn't work. Thank you @Tyler V !

Comment: The function returns a tuple (two values). You can get them and print them however you want. I added an example to the answer.